# Django filter on two fields of the same foreign key object

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset

I have a database schema similar to this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    … (Some fields irrelevant for this query)

class UserNotifiy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    target = models.ForeignKey(<Some other Model>)
    notification_level = models.SmallPositivIntegerField(choices=(1,2,3))
```

Now I want to query for all Users that have a UserNotify object for a specific target and at least a specific notification level (e.g. 2).

If I do something like this:

```
User.objects.filter(usernotify__target=desired_target,
    usernotify__notification_level__gte=2)
```

I get all Users that have a UserNotify object for the specified target and at least one UserNotify object with a notification_level greater or equal to 2. These two UserNotify objects, however, do not have to be identical.

I am aware that I can do something like this:

```
user_ids = UserNotify.objects.filter(target=desired_target,
    notification_level__gte=2).values_list('user_id', flat=True)
users = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids).distinct()
```

But this seems a step too much for me and I believe it executes two queries.

Is there a way to solve my problem with a single query?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question, you say you want that query and that the query is working, what is the exact problem? What do you mean identical objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking for this behaviour but I've never found a better way than the one you describe (creating a query for user ids and inject it in a User query). Note this is not bad since if your database support subqueries, your code should fire only one request composed by a query and a subquery.

However, if you just need a particular field from the User objects (for example first_name), you may try

```
qs = (UserNotify.objects
    .filter(target=desired_target, notification_level__gte=2)
    .values_list('user_id', 'user__first_name')
    .order_by('user_id')
    .distinct('user_id')
)
```

Comment: This syntax is only supported by Postgres

Comment: True I just noticed it... And when you use distinct(*fields) syntax you must aswell provide an order_by with first fields matching the distinct fields. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Comment: It seems that you are correct. My proposed solution for the problem only creates one query with one subquery. Since there seems to be no better solution without subqueries I guess this is the way to go. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't see how you can run the first query, given that `usernotify` is not a valid field name for `User`.

You should start from `UserNotify` as you did in your second example:

```
UserNotify.objects.filter(
    target=desired_target,
    notification_level__gte=2
).select_related('user').values('user').distinct()
```

Comment: The 'field' usernotify is used for the reverse lookup of the foreign key relationship, much as usernotify_set can be used in Python code.

Comment: Your proposed code only gives me the id's of the users, giving me no advantage over the solution I proposed, as I still need to start an extra query to get the information of the User objects.

Comment: @TimSchneider If you need other (given) fields and you are working on postgres, then look at trecouvr answer. Otherwise, you'd have to stick with a second query, unless you want to get distinct users purely in python.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but:

```
class User(models.Model):
    … (Some fields irrelevant for this query)

class UserNotifiy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="notifications")
    target = models.ForeignKey(<Some other Model>)
    notification_level = models.SmallPositivIntegerField(choices=(1,2,3))
```

Then

```
users = User.objects.select_related('notifications').filter(notifications__target=desired_target,
    notifications__notification_level__gte=2).distinct('id')

for user in users:
    notifications = [x for x in user.notifications.all()]
```

I don't have my vagrant box handy now, but I believe this should work.